# Webi SAP BO Sum in block depending on two dimensions

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am trying to sum every line in a table summarizing it by two fields in Webi.

I have a table with the following columns:

`Risk, Year, AssessedBy, Weight, Value.`

I have filtered the table by `Year = 2018 and Risk = "01"`. Thus, I only have the info for that year and that risk.

Each person assessing has a different weight in the final valuation by risk and year. What I have done is divide the assessing person's weight by the total sum of every Weight in the table `[ sum(weight) in block ]`.

The problem is that when I delete the filter, the in block clause makes that the total sum of the weights changes to the total sum of the weights for every year in the table.

I would need something to calculate the total sum for each year and risk.

Comment: It should be something like in block by year and risk.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to provide a fuller understanding of your situation?

Comment: I have just solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved it! Just see Sumal Kunir answer: http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=971131

=sum([Var_a] for each(Dimension;dimension)) In (Demension)

where var_a is the measure, foreach defines a background to base in and in defines the level at which you want to aggregate.