# How to Sum without the numbers from duplicate rows?

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have this set of table on my report:

| Order Id | Denomination | Unit Amount | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04214214421412 | 100 | 80000 | 1 |
| 04214214421412 | 50 | 50000 | 2 |
| 0215424214214214 | 100 | 90000 | 1 |
| 21421421421 | 50 | 6000 | 1 |
| 21421421421 | 100 | 5000 | 2 |
| 909992134213 | 100 | 3000 | 2 |

I have made the below two separate tables to sum with only two columns and it returns the right sum values:

Table 1

| Denom (=[Denomination]) | Total Amount (=Sum[Unitamount] Where ([Code] = 1)) |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 170000 |
| 50 | 6000 |

Table 2

| Denom (=[Denomination]) | Total Amount (=Sum[Unitamount] Where ([Code] = 2)) |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 8000 |
| 50 | 5000 |

I added a dimension to give the main table specific datetime which duplicate some of the rows:

| Order Id | Denomination | Unit Amount | code | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04214214421412 | 100 | 80000 | 1 | 09-02-03 01:02:33 |
| 04214214421412 | 100 | 80000 | 1 | 09-02-03 01:02:35 |
| 04214214421412 | 100 | 80000 | 1 | 09-02-03 01:02:38 |
| 04214214421412 | 50 | 50000 | 2 | 09-02-03 01:02:36 |
| 04214214421412 | 50 | 50000 | 2 | 09-02-03 01:02:34 |
| 0215424214214214 | 100 | 90000 | 1 | 09-02-03 01:02:37 |
| 0215424214214214 | 100 | 90000 | 1 | 09-02-03 01:02:39 |
| 21421421421 | 50 | 6000 | 1 | 09-02-03 01:02:39 |
| 21421421421 | 50 | 6000 | 1 | 09-02-03 01:02:41 |
| 21421421421 | 100 | 5000 | 2 | 09-02-03 01:02:43 |
| 909992134213 | 100 | 3000 | 2 | 09-02-03 01:02:39 |
| 909992134213 | 100 | 3000 | 2 | 09-02-03 01:02:42 |

So the other two tables get affected, all the duplicated rows are being counted:

| Denom =[Denomination] | Total Amount =Sum[Unitamount] Where ([Code] = 1) |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 420000 |
| 50 | 12000 |

Table 2

| Denom =[Denomination] | Total Amount =Sum[Unitamount] Where ([Code] = 2) |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 11000 |
| 50 | 10000 |

How to get the sum value like it's before I added the new dimension?

I have already tried setting the cardinalities between tables on data foundation (one to one, one to many, etc.) I also used `ForEach`, `ForAll` and `In` functions on the `sum` formula but the result is either #Multivalue or the same.

Thank you.

Comment: to be clear the rows aren't duplciated.  The addition of the timestamp clearly shows different values.; as a reuslt the values aren' tduplicated. However.  in SQL there's a concept of window functions which allows you to aggregrate distinct data partitioning the data.  I'm pretty sure WebI has a similar feature.  One idea which comes to mind is to assign a rank column for each order, denom, unit amount and code, ordered by time.  Then sum only when rank is 1 which would then eliminate the fanned  *duplicated") records due to timestmap.

Comment: This https://answers.sap.com/questions/456538/window-function-option-in-webi-report.html also gives some insight on how one might accomplish it using just a show hide variable where you sum only those reocrds to "Show"  or perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951760/webi-sap-bo-sum-in-block-depending-on-two-dimensions